# Getting rid of user-agent stylesheet rules?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, reset

Something odd is happening in my Chome 12.

I downloaded the latest boilerplate a few days ago and designed on it. Everything was ok.

5 minutes ago, Chrome (Webkit) all of a sudden decided to insert extra css rules in my design:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

How do I get rid of this, without adding extra resets?

Edit: also met the problem with h1 elements

```
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
```

Edit2: my reset contains

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup,
 var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, 
tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, 
header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video
 { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; }
```

Comment: Are these not overridden by `margin:0`?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: display:inline-block ?

Comment: No, the question was already answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pff, there were misformated comments in my css files, which disabled the reset...

Comment: Well, that would explain it :)

Comment: Good answer. Next time someone asks me a similar question I'll direct them here.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a mis-formatted comment? I think I'm having the same issue

Comment: I just forgot the "*/" at the end I thing.

Comment: This is why we have syntax highlighting, folks

Comment: This helped. Initially my custom CSS was styling my site, then all of a sudden, the user agent started doing so. Using this comment, I validated my css here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input and I did find some invalid commenting I did. Removing that restored my custom CSS styles.

Answer (score 13):

Those properties are overridden by `margin` and `padding`.

Just set `margin: 0; padding: 0` if you want the `margin` and `padding` gone.

Those properties didn't just suddenly appear, they've been there since forever.

Proof by demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/VNh3u/ - *(obviously, check in a WebKit browser)*

Comment: Yes but `margin: 3em 0 1em 0; padding: 0;` leaves the `-webkit-margin-*` options intact.

Comment: @Forbesmyester: No, it doesn't. Show a http://jsfiddle.net/ example and state your browser/version.

Comment: Since this question has a lot of views... you can't "get rid of" user agent stylesheet rules, what you do instead is override the properties you need to (`h1 { margin: 0; }` to override the default `h1` margin, for example). This might also be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements

Comment: You might need to adjust h1 to be display:inline-block;