# HTML a list of all tags for which the pointer cursor is default for Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, cursor

I'm looking for a list of all tags for which the pointer cursor is default for Chrome

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know, but out of curiosity what is it for? I suppose it doesn't matter to most people since you could style every element to have a pointer using `* { cursor: pointer !important; }` in your CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately it's going to depend on the browser.

For instance an 'a' tag in IE uses the default cursor, whereas webkit will change it to 'pointer'.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do - but ultimately I would use a reset if this is a code issue.

Answer (score 1):

Except 'input' and 'a' tags, all tags will have default cursor only.

For Input : Text
For 'A' tag : hand

Comment: I actually found that the input type="image" has the pointer cursor as default

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but according to [this excellent related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867287/1879728) you can find the default stylesheet for the Blink renderer used in Chrome [here](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css). The elements having `cursor: pointer;` are only `a`, `area` and two `input` fields, the exact definitions being:

```css
input[type="password" i]::-internal-reveal:focus
input[type="image" i]
area:-webkit-any-link
a:-webkit-any-link
```

(I would have also expected `button` and `input[type=submit]` but a quick test seems to indicate they really show the default cursor)