# Copy Chrome default input's outline style

Tags: css, google-chrome

How can I set the default Chrome input's outline style (on focus, the orange one), so it looks the same in every browser? Chrome style seems to be `textarea:focus{outline: rgb(229, 151, 0) auto 5px; outline-offset: -2px}`, however it doesn't work (there is no `auto` for `outline-style` for other browsers).

Comment: Check my answer. Hope that it helps. ;)

Answer (score 34):

[default Chrome outline-style:](http://i.shotnes.com/cob8u64y)

```
outline-color: rgb(77, 144, 254); // #4D90FE
outline-offset: -2px;
outline-style: auto;
outline-width: 5px;
```

convert to this

```
 input:focus {
     outline:none; 
     border:1px solid #4D90FE;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px  #4D90FE;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px  #4D90FE;
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

Don't know if my solution is good enough for you, but so far, i don't know any other way... I do it like this:

```
textarea:focus
{
    outline:none; /*or outline-color:#FFFFFF; if the first doesn't work*/
    border:1px solid #48A521;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #48A521;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #48A521;
}
```

Comment: +1. This is the closest you can get to "auto" in other browsers. Fiddle a little with the border color and shadow transparency, and it can look quite similar.

Answer (score 2):

With Chrome 60 the outline is now blue.

The auto style of outline creates a one pixel outline, with the corners "notched".

This can be achieved using ::before and ::after rules like so:

```
DIV.someclass--focus {
    outline:none; 
    border: 1px solid #86A8DF !important;
}
DIV.someclass--focus::before {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    content: ' ';
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #A6C8FF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A6C8FF;
}
DIV.someclass--focus::after {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    content: ' ';
    border-left: 1px solid #A6C8FF;
    border-right: 1px solid #A6C8FF;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

The first rule changes the border color.

The second rule provides a top and bottom border that starts one pixel in from the left and ends one pixel in from the right.

The thirder rule provides a left and right border that starts one down from the top, and ends one pixel up from the bottom.

CAVEAT: the containing element must be explicitly "position: relative" in order for the ::before/::after absolute positioning to work.

The classname "someclass-focus" is meaningless... it just has to be applied/removed whenever you want the pseudo focus outline to appear/disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, really.

Chrome uses the 'auto' outline-style (whatever that may mean) and that isn't according to the CSS3 specs.

Your best option is to create your own highlight styling and (and at least) overwrite the outline-style. That way all browsers will have the same focus element for your page.

Copying the chrome style is very hard to do. Since css by default doesn't support a shadow-like outline, only solid, dashed, etc styles are supported. You will have to mimick it using box-shadow, however, this will, for some odd reason, cause the border of the input box to show (in inset style), which forces you to define the border of the input box.

You could do something like this for example:

```
input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px blue;
  outline-style: none;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dstibbe/2wr0pge2/2/

Answer (score -3):

Try here:

[Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements/6867287#6867287)

You have the default CSS of Google Chrome there. I'm sure the style will be defined there.

P.S.: You will want **Chrome/Safari (WebKit)**.

Comment: In my question I already posted the Chrome style and pointed out, that it doesn't work in other browsers.

Comment: Maybe you can override other browsers' stylesheets with `!important`?

Comment: It won't change anything. It seems, that Chrome has some special settings, which cannot be achieved by css. As I already said, it uses `auto` as `outline-style` and it has no meaning for other browsers.

Comment: Have you tried the different `outline-style` options? Some of it must be the one Chrome has set has auto...
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline-style.asp

Comment: This is a link-only answer.

Answer (score -4):

If you inspect any input tag with the styles panel open in Chrome you should see the default user agent stylesheet properties. Use the colour picker in Web developer tools or the chrome colour picker plugin to get the rgb value.

Comment: In my question I already posted the Chrome style and pointed out, that it doesn't work in other browsers.

Comment: Then you'll need to fake the effect you are looking to achieve using other CSS options or some variation on [Textarea Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/)