# Why is outline-width being ignored?

Tags: html, css, outline

I noticed that when I set `outline-style: auto` in my CSS then the outline is always 2px wide, regardless of `outline-width`, unless `outline-width` is 0, then there is no outline.

Why do browsers ignore `outline-width` in this case and how can I change the width? (I know I can use `outline-style: solid` but it just doesn't give the same effect).

```css
div {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  outline-color: dodgerblue;
  outline-style: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="outline-width: 0px">0px</div>
<div style="outline-width: 1px">1px</div>
<div style="outline-width: 10px">10px</div>
<div style="outline-width: 1em">1em</div>
```

Comment: which browser do you use ? mine does reset width

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tested it across multiple browsers? Does the issue appear the same across all the browsers you tested? I see this from the example you provided: http://i.imgur.com/mSLG31r.png

Comment: Not an answer, but this may be helpful in what I think you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324960/copy-chrome-default-inputs-outline-style

Answer (score 1):

*If you use for example `outline-style: solid;` it will work*

Not acknowledge the width set when style is `auto` is reported as a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402874), Edge/IE11 does not render it unless a style is set, other than `auto`, and Firefox render `auto` as `solid`

W3C say: (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#outline-style)

> The `auto` value permits the user agent to render a custom outline
>   style, typically a style which is either a user interface default for
>   the platform, or perhaps a style that is richer than can be described
>   in detail in CSS, e.g. a rounded edge outline with semi-translucent
>   outer pixels that appears to glow. As such, this specification does
>   not define how the `outline-color` is incorporated or used (if at all)
>   when rendering auto style outlines. User agents may treat `auto` as
>   `solid`.

```css
div {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  outline-color: red;
  outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="outline-width: 0px">0px</div>
<div style="outline-width: 1px">1px</div>
<div style="outline-width: 10px">10px</div>
<div style="outline-width: 1em">1em</div>
```

Comment: You missed the part where it says "(I know I can use outline-style: solid but it just doesn't give the same effect)"

Comment: @BoltClock So does not my 2:nd paragraph in my answer, the italic one, answer that?

Comment: @BoltClock Added a ref. from W3C

Answer (score 1):

When `outline-style` is `auto`, browsers draw custom, platform-specific outlines. This may result in them ignoring any or all of the other outline properties if they're not supported by their custom outline implementations. This means you may not be able to customize the width of the outline.

Interestingly, the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#outline-props) only mentions browsers being free to ignore `outline-color`, even though it doesn't make sense to force them to honor arbitrary non-zero values of `outline-width` when drawing platform-specific outlines that might not even support arbitrary widths in the first place (as is most likely the case with whatever browser you're testing this in).

Note that Firefox treats `outline-style: auto` as `outline-style: solid` (which is mentioned in the spec, too), which means it *will* render outlines with the width you specify. IE and Microsoft Edge do not appear to support `outline-style: auto` at all, which makes all of this irrelevant to those browsers (I'd have at least expected Microsoft Edge to treat it as solid since that's how Windows 10 draws focus styles by default anyway, but I digress).