# CSS cross child node for all doctype

Tags: html, css, xhtml

For example, I would like to know whether the color green will be 
on character AAA and BBB inside of `div` tag for all doctype such as xhtml, html5, html ?

```
<div style='color:green'>AAA<a>BBB</a></div>
```

But I tried it and  AAA will be green and BBB will be black as default browser css color.
In other words: parent tag style (defined by inline style or any other css method) won't affect child node style for all the mentioned doctypes. Right ?

where I can know the css spec in more detail about this ?

Comment: I find it really unclear what you're asking..

Comment: I think we shouldn't downvote this, OP seems to be confused with the inheritance and also, using invalid HTML, give some time to fix

Comment: Now you may understand my question more after re-edit.

Comment: You want the link of website where it is specified about these rules??

Comment: I want to know my css concept is wrong or not ? And  good website to talk about this that is welcome

Comment: Well all the element will take the default property of the browser if you have not specified it.. like here it has taken <a>BBB</a> as black... So if you want to impose the color on all the child element you can try div.green * { color: green; }...

Comment: Something like this? 

http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Comment: Doctype is an HTML concept. CSS is about styling this HTML code. (graphical) Browsers have a **default** stylesheet but it's up to them to choose one for HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0. It's [something along this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) but there's no default for form elements for example: depends on browser AND OS (`fieldset > legend` selector in Firefox, `-webkit-appearance` in WebKit: kingdom of whatever they want)

Comment: From your example pasted in jsfiddle and seen with Firefow/Windows, BBB is also green. But with `<div style='color:green'>AAA<a href="#">BBB</a></div>` it's blue (or purple if :visited) because there's a default CSS for links (links have an `href` attribute)

Comment: why css will be different for with href or without href ?

Comment: FelipeAls, you are right, I understand what you said, when I put href link in a tag the color is changed to blur/purple. Where Can i find all those default browser css color ?

Comment: it is asked before  in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to say.

There may or may not be a CSS rule with [an `!important` flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) that would override the green for AAA.

There may or may not be a CSS rule that sets the `color` property of the `<a>` element to something other than [`inherit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#value-def-inherit).

Comment: set inline style on every child node that will definitly be correct and safe but it will have a lot redunctant work and it will increase the html file size if not use css with css file with class