# css list on Wordpress being defined differently then I want it to for a section, how can I fix it?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using wordpress. I have a theme that is overwriting the lists.

So I guess I need to add my own class for lists.

I added a new div tag before I started my lists, but I guess I am still inside the other div tag that the system uses.

So how do I redeclare what I want the lists to do?

I just want them to be normal.

So I can add a custom div to the style.css
that the theme calls.

I just don't know what I need to force the css to say.

For example in the css I could do:

`.clearList`
as the name of the new div then define the lists to be normal, but how do I do that?

Then in the HTML I could just do:

```
<pre><div id="clearList">

<ul style="list-style-type: circle;">
<li>all the HTML</li>
<li>with lists here</li>
</ul>

</div></pre>
```

Anyone know what I mean and how to do it?
thanks,
Richard

Comment: I think I'm so tired, I may have confused you.

What I mean to say is that if I want the list to behave normally, how do I define it in a new CSS field so that I can use it without changing the behaviour for the rest of the theme.

Comment: Oh, I just seen there is a wordpress stack exchange where I can ask this type of question. I did not know this was not the place for that. Sorry everyone. I'll go there and ask.

Comment: I suspect you meant `<div class="clearList">` in your code sample :)

Comment: Yes, I did mean that. It still is not working though.

Comment: Does anyone know where to find the normal CSS for the lists?
I don't know the normal indentations, etc.

Comment: Have a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6867287/13019

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the list styles for each div you're using, so you can have various list styles  depending on the particular list.

```
 div.clearlist li { /* some style */ }
```

as well as that, you might want to style the child elements

```
 div.clearlist > ul li { /* some style */ }
```

You can repeat this with other divs, should you wish.

Comment: exactly. I have to declare how to display them. But I don't know the CSS for the normal behaviours, like how far to indent them, how to make the circles, circles, how to make the numbers, digits or leading with a 0 digits, roman numerals, etc.

Comment: An '<ol>' is an ordered list with numerals, which can be styled differently to an '<ul>' (Ordered list and unordered list). 

You can use list-style-type to set particular styles. Read more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: Yeah, I did use style="list-style-type: decimal" for numbers and use the different ones I got from w3schools

But for some reason, the lists are still just showing up as just like line breaks, no indents, no numbers, alpha, anything.

Comment: Can you put '!important' after your styles. This should overwrite the ones the theme is setting by default.

Comment: just tested it, it did not work. :(

<ul style="list-style-type:upper-alpha !important;">

Comment: You want to style this in the css, or remove the previous css styles in the css rather than in the <ul> itself. This should solve the issue.

Comment: I am working on that now... making different ones for each of the ones I am using...

div.clearlist ul.ua {list-style-type:upper-alpha;}
div.clearlist ul.lr {list-style-type:lower-roman;}
etc.

after I'm done, I'll update this to say if it fixed it or not.

Comment: You should try one sample one first to make sure it's working.

Comment: I used Search and replace to do it fast in the whole thing...

Here are the div css I created:

div.clearlist ul.ua {list-style-type:upper-alpha;}
div.clearlist ul.lr {list-style-type:lower-roman;}
div.clearlist ul.la {list-style-type:lower-alpha;}
div.clearlist ul.ulc {list-style-type:circle;}
div.clearlist ul.uld {list-style-type:decimal;}

then replaced them all in the ul tags.

I tested it on that jsfiddle and it works.
But in the page it is still not working.

No idea why it won't work. :(

Comment: Can you link to the actual website at all so we can see? Also, try make those styles !important and maybe it'll override the others.

Comment: I added the !important and it did not fix it. I was creating a order form using Gravity forms, this is in a HTML section. Maybe it is not using CSS5, which I think that CSS Code is for, right?

Not sure. At any rate, I'm just going to create the agreement on Micorosoft Word and use a signature page online, and have them order it that way. Have to get it done today, as a client wants to order it. So I had to give up. Maybe Later I can fix it for the future orders to be automated.

Thank You for trying to help. Greatly appreciated!