# Centering HTML input field for iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, input, time

I'm trying to center the value of an input field (not the placeholder). Somehow iOS doesn't "recognize" the centering, however firefox, safari and chrome do.

HTML

```
<input type="time" value="12:00">
```

CSS

```
input {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5%;

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;

  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-size: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

The result should be a yellow box containing the time 12:00 centered, on an iOS devices it doesn't work.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9TPM/4/

Answer (score 2):

Input element is mysterious. Some browsers have `inline-block` value set for display property and some browsers have `inline` value.

And inline elements cannot have the width and so it cannot align the text to the right or center.

Thus, in your case, the browsers defaulting to the `inline-block` value for the display property will have alignment effect. But it would not which browsers defaults to the `inline` value.

Thus, setting display property explicitly will make you relief behind the scene. Just set the display property to `inline-block` or `block` to have it's width or alignment.

FYI, most of the browsers should render the display property of input element to `inline-block`. Here's a quick reference: [default css for html elemnts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements).

Answer (score 1):

```
display: block;
```

did the magic, for whatever reasons it is needed for iOS but not for Desktops.. if someone has an explenation I'm happy to hear it