# Wrong position of Table by Script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the next CSS:

```
.table {
    position:static;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Obviously I used them where they belong. But I also added some script in other page:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(300/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(300/2);
    window.open('page.aspx?' + window.location.href.toString().split('?')[1], 'PopUp', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=300, height=300, top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
    window.open('', '_self').close(); 
</script>
```

All what I wanted for many hours, was to be in the correct position, no white line between top and left. And I don't realize what else I have to do.

Help is always welcome.

Comment: html, body {margin:0; padding: 0}

Comment: Also see: [Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements?rq=1) ... the default margin on the body is 8px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is another style

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;
}
```