# Safari displaying an Unexpected “error”, why?

Tags: html, css, safari

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Types of Internet Connections</title>
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    section {
        border: 3px solid lightblue;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: scroll;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    h1 {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <section>
        <h1>Dial-up</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Slower</strong> than other internet connection             types</li>
            <li>Connects through <storng>existing phone lines</storng> using a dial-up modem</li>
            <li>Generally the cheapest option, but requires   <strong>phone service</strong></li>
            <li>Must "<strong>dial up</strong>" to connect to the internet and <storng>disconnect</storng> when done</li>
            <li><strong>Cannot use internet and phone at the same time</strong> (unless there are multiple phone lines)</li>
        </ul> 
    </section>
    // other members，etc
    </body>
    </html>
```

I was practicing "inline-block", but there is a unexpected display in Safari, and the page in chrome and firefox is well displayed.

What wrong with Safari, i can't find the reason, can anyone tell me?
thank you!

Comment: Post your actual code please, not pictures of it.

Comment: Only image style code, only hardcore ! :)

Comment: I have posted my actual code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vertical-align`

Try this:

```
.yourclass{
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: "vertical-align: top" fixed my Safari error, but could you tell me the reason?

Comment: Because inline-block is a inline element, and inline elements side by side are and can be vertical align by this rule

Comment: could you tell me why my Safari made this unexpected "error"?

Comment: I really don´t know a lot of safari, but maybe the browser default is `vertical-align: bottom` or there is no vertical at all and gets to the bottom

Comment: Could you tell me how can i get the browser(e.g. Safari, Chrome, Firefox) default settings of html element?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements