# Is default padding defined to be 0 for divs?

Tags: html, css, padding

What is the default padding value for div elements?
Is default value defined or its up to the UA/browsers?

Edit: Can you please provide reference to specs along with the answer.

Edit2: Its a varied response : 1) Its 0, without any reference or explanation. 2) It depends on browser. 3) Comments stated that there is no discussion for DIV. So RESPECTED DOWNVOTERS would you care to explain the reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Comment: Its a varied response : 1) Its 0, without any reference or explanation. 2) It depends on browser. 3) Comments stated that there is no discussion for DIV. So RESPECTED DOWNVOTERS would you care to explain the reasons for the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the default padding value for div elements?

It is 0

Comment: A reference to spec or something would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what browser you're using. Most people will use a reset/normalize script to make sure styles are consistent throughout browsers.

Comment: For DIV there's no discussion. Otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements