# Angular2 css :host applying but not visible in browser

Tags: css, angular

I am having a bizarre issue whilst creating my first `Angular2` app.

I am applying some CSS to a **component host** (`example-component`) yet it doesn't appear in the browser?

This is my first time posting for Angular in SO, so hopefully I include everything needed to attain some help.

---

**example.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'crate',
  templateUrl: './app/folderA/folderAB/crate.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/folderA/folderAB/crate.css']
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

---

**index.html**

---

**crate.html**

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**crate.css**

```
:host-context(.lg){
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

---

What I don't understand, is that I open this in chrome & firefox, and I see the following CSS stated under rules for `example.component`.

```
.lg[_nghost-ims-2], .lg [_nghost-ims-2] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

[image: Firefox]

It is correctly applying the CSS to `example-component`, but it is not being displayed / rendered in browser. What am I doing wrong / missing?

---

### EDIT

The exact same issue applies even if I change `crate.css` to:

```
crate{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Comment: change 'styleUrls' to 'styles'?

Comment: change `:host-context (.lg){}` to `:host .lg{}` and check.

Comment: @micronyks Doesn't apply it to the element.

Comment: There are many other ways to do it.

Comment: Its working. maybe browser issue. try to run with chrome.

Comment: @micronyks I have tried it in chrome, firefox & IE - all yield the same result. I don't understand why it's applying, but isn't getting rendered.

Comment: check this https://plnkr.co/edit/ukANx4wcCYFXvx2BXWly?p=preview its working as expected without encapsulation. I also checked with mozilla and its working.

Comment: @micronyks I don't understand - http://imgur.com/BKsToTn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125823/discussion-between-micronyks-and-zze).

Comment: Add `display: block` to your stylesheet, if this works I'll try to elaborate a longer answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any component with an unrecognized tagName like `<crate></crate>` is created as a [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement) and has empty values for all the style properties, if you want it to behave like a `div` then add `display: block;` to your stylesheet.

See [Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements) for additional resources on the default css for different browsers.

Comment: I will check this out as soon as possible - thanks for the answer.