# What is the default value for the CSS color property in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

This Mozilla article mentions that the initial value for the CSS `color` property varies from one browser to the next.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color

What is the initial value used by the Chrome browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies by element and platform .

Hopefully [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements/6867287#6867287) will help you but you can [see the chrome default user agent stylesheet here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps https://themeforest.net/forums/thread/google-chrome-placeholder-color/62392

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: inherit; }
```