# Sample HTML Document That Includes All Tags

Tags: html

Does anyone know where I might find a **single** HTML document that includes an example of every non-depricated tag in the HTML5 specification?

I want to compare default styling (of such a document) across all browsers.

If you have (or can locate) an example, please post the HTML in your answer along with a link to its source. Links go bad over time, so pasting the HTML itself will preserve the usefulness of your answer over time.

Comment: https://html.com/deprecated/ this may help you

Comment: This link shows every tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ As for a HTML document which includes all the tags, I am not sure where you would find this

Comment: Courtesy of MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5 <- not sure if it's 100% what you're looking for but probs worth a read

Comment: This sounds like a project you could start.... register the domain name `everyhtml5tag.org` and make the page from the resources given above. This could actually be extremely useful.  And with appropriate links (on the page) people can donate to you for it.

Comment: I found something else quite useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867287/217867). However, I'd still like to compare an actual page across browsers. You'd think there would be at least one page on the internet including all tags, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your best bet is to make one yourself. If you are too lazy to make it here's one I did: https://pastebin.com/QU4kcJfz

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> TEST HTML PAGE </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Most of HTML5 tags">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5, tags">
    <meta name="author" content="http://blazardsky.space">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <p>HEADER</p>
            <menu type="context" id="navmenu">
                <menuitem label="Home" icon="icon.png"> <a href="#">Home</a> </menuitem>
            </menu>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h1> Heading... </h1>
        <h2> Heading... </h2>
        <h3> Heading... </h3>
        <h4> Heading... </h4>
        <h5> Heading... </h5>
        <h6> Heading... </h6>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nisi lacus, auctor sit amet purus vel, gravida luctus lectus. Aenean rhoncus dapibus enim, sit amet faucibus leo ornare vitae. <br>
            <span> span </span>
            <b>Bold word</b>
            <i>italic</i>
            <em>emphasis</em>
            <mark>mark</mark>
            <small> small </small>
            <sub> sub </sub>
            <sup> sup </sup>
            <u> Statements... </u>
            <abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration">NASA</abbr>
            <strike> strikethrough </strike>
            <span><del> deprecated info </del> <ins> new info </ins> </span>
            <s> not relevant </s>
            <a href="#link">link</a>
            <time datetime="2020-08-17 08:00">Monday at 8:00 AM</time>
            <ruby>
                <rb>ruby base<rt>annotation
            </ruby>
            <br>
            <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CANC</kbd>
        </p>
    </main>

    <p> This is a <q>short quote</q> </p>
    <blockquote> This instead is a long quote that is going to use a lot of words and also cite who said that. —<cite>Some People</cite> </blockquote>

    <ol>
        <li><data value="21053">data tag</data></li>
        <li><data value="23452">data tag</data></li>
        <li><data value="42545">data tag</data></li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
    </ol>

    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
    </ul>

    <hr>

    <template>
        <h2>Hidden content (after page loaded).</h2>
    </template>

    <video width="640" height="480" src="https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4" controls>
        <track kind="subtitles" src="subtitles_de.vtt" srclang="de">
        <track kind="subtitles" src="subtitles_en.vtt" srclang="en">
        <track kind="subtitles" src="subtitles_ja.vtt" srclang="ja">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 <code>video</code>, but you can
        download this video from the <a href="https://archive.org/details/Popeye_forPresident" target="_blank">Internet Archive</a>.
    </video>

    <object data="flashmovie.swf" width="600" height="800" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        Please install the Shockwave plugin to watch this movie.
    </object>

    <pre>

                                                                             _,'/
                                                                    _.-''._:
                                                    ,-:`-.-'    .:.|
                                                 ;-.''       .::.|
                    _..------.._  / (:.       .:::.|
             ,'.   .. . .  .`/  : :.     .::::.|
         ,'. .    .  .   ./    \ ::. .::::::.|
     ,'. .  .    .   . /      `.,,::::::::.;\
    /  .            . /       ,',';_::::::,:_:
 / . .  .   .      /      ,',','::`--'':;._;
: .             . /     ,',',':::::::_:'_,'
|..  .   .   .   /    ,',','::::::_:'_,'
|.              /,-. /,',':::::_:'_,'
| ..    .    . /) /-:/,'::::_:',-'
: . .     .   // / ,'):::_:',' ;
 \ .   .     // /,' /,-.','  ./
    \ . .  `::./,// ,'' ,'   . /
     `. .   . `;;;,/_.'' . . ,'
        ,`. .   :;;' `:.  .  ,'
     /   `-._,'  ..  ` _.-'
    (     _,'``------'' 
     `--''

    </pre>

    <code>
        // code tag
        #include <iostream>

            using namespace std;

            int main()
            {
            cout << "Hello World!" << endl; return 0; } </code> <p>
                <var> variable </var> = 1000;
                <samp>Traceback (most recent call last):<br>NameError: name 'variabl' is not defined</samp>
                </p>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Numbers</th>
                            <th>Letters</th>
                            <th>Colors</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td>123</td>
                            <td>ABC</td>
                            <td>RGB</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                            <td>Red</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>B</td>
                            <td>Green</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>C</td>
                            <td>Blue</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <p> A <dfn>definition</dfn> is an explanation of the meaning of a word or phrase. </p>

                <details>
                    <summary>Summary of content below</summary>
                    <p>Content 1</p>
                    <p>Content 2</p>
                    <p>Content 3</p>
                    <p>Content 4</p>
                </details>
                <section>
                    <h1>Content</h1>
                    <p>Informations about content.</p>
                </section>

                <progress value="33" max="100"></progress>
                <meter value="11" min="0" max="45" optimum="40">25 out of 45</meter>

                <p> 2+2 = <output>4</output> </p>

                <select>
                    <optgroup label="Choice [1-3]">
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Choice [4-6]">
                        <option value="4">Four</option>
                        <option value="5">Five</option>
                        <option value="6">Six</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>

                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p> div > div > p </p>
                    </div>

                    <br>


                </div>
                <svg width="100" height="100">
                    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
                </svg>

                <br>

                <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="4" cols="50">
        Write something in here
    </textarea>

                <br>

                <audio controls>
                    I'm sorry. You're browser doesn't support HTML5 <code>audio</code>.
                    <source src="https://archive.org/download/ReclaimHtml5/ReclaimHtml5.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                    <source src="https://archive.org/download/ReclaimHtml5/ReclaimHtml5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
                <p>This is a recording of a talk called <cite>Reclaim HTML5</cite> which was orinally delieved in Vancouver at a <a href="http://www.meetup.com/vancouver-javascript-developers/" taget="_blank">Super VanJS Meetup</a>. It is hosted by <a href="https://archive.org/details/ReclaimHtml5"
                     target="_blank">The Internet Archive</a> and licensed under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/legalcode" target="_blank">CC 3.0</a>.</p>

                <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=spotify%3Atrack%3A67HxeUADW4H3ERfaPW59ma?si=PogFcGg9QqapyoPbn2lVOw" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>

                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h2>Title of Article</h2>
                        <span>by Arthur T. Writer</span>
                    </header>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam volutpat sollicitudin nisi, at convallis nunc semper et. Donec ultrices odio ac purus facilisis, at mollis urna finibus.</p>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/600x300" alt="placeholder-image">
                        <figcaption> Caption.</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <footer>
                        <dl> <dt>Published</dt>
                            <dd>17 August 2020</dd> <dt>Tags</dt>
                            <dd>Sample Posts, html example</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </footer>
                </article>

                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
                        <input name="name" id="name"><br>
                        <label for="dob">Date of Birth<label><br>
                                <input name="dob" id="dob" type="date">
                    </fieldset>
                </form>

                <aside>
                    <p> P inside ASIDE tag </p>
                </aside>
                <map name="shapesmap"> <area shape="rect" coords="29,32,230,215" href="#square" alt="Square"> <area shape="circle" coords="360,130,100" href="#circle" alt="Circle"> </map>

                <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="placeholder-image">

                <form action="" method="get">
                    <label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
                    <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
                    <datalist id="browsers">
                        <option value="Edge">
                        <option value="Firefox">
                        <option value="Chrome">
                        <option value="Opera">
                        <option value="Safari">
                    </datalist>
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>

                <footer>
                    <address> relevant contacts <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">mail</a>.</address>
                    <div> created by <a href="https://blazardsky.space">@blazardsky</a></div>
                </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I have found [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/cbracco/html5-test-page/blob/master/index.html) which provides a quite complete and well-built webpage. It only lacks some longer paragraphs to bulletproof your styling (for instance, if you want to use it to set up your base CSS for your website) and some nesting in list (`ul`, `ol` and `dl` with multiple sub-levels).

There's also [this one](http://www.u-d-a.com/html-markup-test-page/) if you want to give it a try.