# H1 tag special design

Tags: html, css, tags

I spent several hours searching for an answer to my question but didn't find anything similar. I have completed web with a lot of design. Now I noticed that I didn't use H1 tag on any page and will want to add H1 tag on navigation titles.

So my question is,

How can I make H1 tag to not have any effects, just to be a normal tag in HTML without style effect on the text?

Comment: If so you can use p or span tag , h1 is use for heading

Comment: I need h1 for SEO, but I don't want to make hidden h1 tags copy when I have already navigation bar just need make H1 don't change a style. Same as the example when I will use <z1></z1>

Comment: do not add `<h1>` on navigation. Navigation should use anchor tags `<a>`. `<h1>` should be used as the main heading of the page. And only once on every page. That's HTML and also SEO best practice. Also, i suggest you first use some `reset` css that resets everything to default. And then start styling.

Comment: I have <a> tag on navigation so you suggest only once use <h1> tag on each page? hmmm, so I already doing it except on index page. Will be good if I hide h1 tag on index page? Please check how I make https://www.maxko-hosting.com/?page=dedicatedservers H1 at top and other text is h3 and h5. Maybe replace it with H2 and H3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  [`all: unset;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) to remove default browser style(then you can set your style if you want to...)

```css
h1{
 all: unset;
}
```

```html
<h1>I am h1 but looks like normal p</h1>
```

**Edit support in IE**

Your alternative is to override browser default style with `!important`

[here is links to default style in each browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements)

For example override IE style:

```css
h1{
font-size: 11pt;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
 <h1>I am h1 but looks like normal p</h1>
 
 <p>this is the default style:</p>
 display: block;
font-size: 24pt;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 14pt 0;
```

Comment: thanks, it did a trick, but I had to add !important at the end. But how to do same for Edge/Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Reassign the h1 tags style as you declared for other tags.
    `h1{font-size:20px !important;.....}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use h1 tag for main headings and customize it according to your requirement. Like:-

```
h1{font-size: 24px;}
```