# Css: How to apply the same list-style-type bullets for html sub-lists?

Tags: css, html-lists

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="general.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/basicDataTypes/list.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="title"> title bar</div>
      <p>option 1 -</p>
      <ul class="ul-ident">
         <li>
            <p>test1:</p>
            <ul class="ul-ident">
               <li>
                  <p>subtest1</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>subtest2</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>subtest3</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>subtest4</p>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test2</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test3</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test4</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test5</p>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <p>option 2 - </p>
      <ul class="ul-ident">
         <li>
            <p>test1</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test2</p>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
   </body>
</html>
```

My css styles is:

```
.title {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-style: solid;

.ul-ident {
    padding-left: 25px;
}


hr {
    width: 90%;
    border: none;
    height: 3px;
    /* Set the hr color */
    color: green; /* old IE */
    background-color: green; /* Modern Browsers */
}
```

I need that all bullets will be in disc style, but got for main list items a disc-bullets and for sub-list items a circle-bullets

I read that "The list items will be marked with bullets (small black circles) by default" (source:[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) )

below current result screenshot:
[image: Different bullets in html sub-list]

I try IE and chrome, and both gives the same result.

**My question: How to make all the bullets in the same list-style-type?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
ul ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-ident">
         <li>
            <p>test1:</p>
            <ul class="ul-ident">
               <li>
                  <p>subtest1</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>subtest2</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>subtest3</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>subtest4</p>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test2</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test3</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test4</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test5</p>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <p>option 2 - </p>
      <ul class="ul-ident">
         <li>
            <p>test1</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p>test2</p>
         </li>
      </ul>
```

Lets dig a bit deeper and wonder how to find out which [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to apply the styles? The simplest way is to use the developer tools. Then mark the elements you are interested in. Then you will see "user agent stylesheet" at the right of the image

[image]

Right below the `ul ul` you will see it overwrites the `ul` which contains the style you are looking for.

**Update after comment:**
You can use CSS [inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) to use styles defined from a parent element to the child element. See in this example, I've added another nesting level. So the first level is defined to `circle`, 2nd level is defined to `square` and all next levels will `inherit` the `square` cause `sqaure` is the defined parent..

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: circle;
}

ul ul {
    list-style-type: square;
}

ul ul ul {
    list-style-type: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>circle
        <ul>
            <li>square
                <ul>
                    <li>inherit
                        <ul>
                            <li>inherit</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would like to know how you can define that all sub-lists will have the same style of the main list, not necessarily the disc style

Comment: Why should I set a list-style-type: disc if it is a default value?
And why at all according to my source code the browser changed the most prominent of the sub-lists?

Comment: the `disc` value is just an example. You can set it what ever you want/need. The browser only displays what you do. If you applied the example I've posted with no classes it will obviously change all elements you select = `ul ul` in CSS is a selector

Comment: got it. But I'm interested in general knowing why even though the default style for the list should be a disc: 1. I should define it explicitly 2. In this sub-list the browser displays different styles

Comment: @C.Mar every browsers has a default defined stylesheet [see this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22510220/2008111) If you don't like it you can use a `CSS reset` (you'll find many if you google) but if you use a CSS reset make sure to add the styles you want **for every element** you just removed the default style with the CSS reset! That means margin, padding for body, p, ul li and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `list-style-type: none;` and use `li:before` and apply style to create the "dot"

```css
.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
}

.ul-ident {
  padding-left: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.ul-ident li {
  position: relative;
}

.ul-ident li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background: black;
  top: 6.5px;
  left: -11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

hr {
  width: 90%;
  border: none;
  height: 3px;
  /* Set the hr color */
  color: green;
  /* old IE */
  background-color: green;
  /* Modern Browsers */
}
```

```html
<div class="title"> title bar</div>
<p>option 1 -</p>
<ul class="ul-ident">
  <li>
    <p>test1:</p>
    <ul class="ul-ident">
      <li>
        <p>subtest1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>subtest2</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>subtest3</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>subtest4</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>test2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>test3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>test4</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>test5</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>option 2 - </p>
<ul class="ul-ident">
  <li>
    <p>test1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>test2</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr>
```