# Getting "natural" display type for HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, display

I have a a web page where various fields are shown or hidden by toggling between "display:block" and "display:none". However, I added some extra stuff to the page and discovered that I needed to special-case several tags: TD needs to use "display:table-cell:, TR needs  to use "display:table-row", and so on...

Is there any general off-the-shelf solution to this (i.e. look up the "natural" display type based on the tag name) or am I stuck with creating a JS object by hand which lists tag names and the corresponding display types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements)

Comment: Thanks for the link. If this is a way of saying "you have to create a JS object of your own", then yes, it does answer the question. :)

Comment: If that's what you want to get out of it. Or, you could actually look at the default stylesheets for the different browsers and analyze them and find that they all have a lot of commonality. For instance, as you noticed, `td` tends to have `display: table-cell` applied to it. But that would mean work on your part; much easier to run some code on the user's browser and waste their cycles...

Comment: As Aravinth mentions below, there is a display:revert option which does exactly that without all the fuss.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `revert` to `display` property to set the element to it's original value and get the original value by Javascript.

```js
const getOriginalDisplayProperty = (elem) => {
  const modifiedDisplayProperty = getDisplayProperty(elem); //store modified display property
  elem.style.display = "revert"; //revert to original display property
  setTimeout(() => {
    elem.style.display = modifiedDisplayProperty; // Again set original display property
  }, 0);
  return getDisplayProperty(elem);
};

const getDisplayProperty = (elem) =>
  window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).display;

getOriginalDisplayProperty(document.querySelector(".test"));
getOriginalDisplayProperty(document.querySelector(".test-span"));
```

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}
span {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<span class="test-span"></span>
```

Comment: Excellent, that's just what I needed. I've never come across this before -- many thanks!