# Where can I find the default rendering rules for the <html> element?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The [CSS Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) defines what should happen with given CSS rules, but doesn't say anything about the default browser stylesheet.

The [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#rendering) recommends default stylesheets, but the height of the `<html>` element is forced to a minimum of 100vh, ignoring rules like `html { height: 50vh; width: 50vw; }`. Additionally, an element never passes CSS values up to its ancestors, with one exception: background styles applied to the `<body>` element are passed to the `<html>` element.

Where can I find the default rendering rules for the `<html>` and `<body>` elements? I imagine there are per-browser rules, so where could I find the ones for Chrome, for example? What CSS rules does the HTML element ignore/ which ones does it enforce? Is this the same for all browsers?

I read the CSS Spec, the HTML Spec, and searched the web for default rendering rules for Chrome, but couldn't find any.

Additional note: opening dev tools on Chrome and manually setting `height: 50vh` and `overflow: hidden` on `<html>` seemingly applies the rules: highlighted area and computed height value is correct; but the entire content still shows up, so it's being ignored/forced.

Comment: I don't know how up to date this is kept but I use this resource: https://meiert.com/en/blog/user-agent-style-sheets/

Comment: *but the height of the <html> element is forced to a minimum of 100vh,* --> this is not true. The height of the html is as tall as the content inside it. html and body are block level elements so they behave as such, nothing special with them (except some propagation style like background and overflow)

Comment: According to the CSS Spec, a background color on a block-level box should only apply to it's height, but setting `html { height:50vh; background: red; overflow: hidden }` still paints the entire viewport in red and shows the entire content without clipping from the `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: `background` or `background-color` for the html tag applies always to the entire viewport and not the entire document. It is a simple common feature for all browsers to color the viewport not just the document in question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I observe as well. If not the CSS Spec and the HTML Spec, who's responsible for overriding these CSS rules? What other rules are overriden? Where can I find that documentation?

Comment: there is no override here, it's a special feature defined in the CSS Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks Temani! Does the CSS Spec defines such a special rule for the overflow rule as well? Is there a place that documents all the special rules for the `html` and `body` elements?

Comment: @AndréCasal - yes it does. The background is propagated to the canvas (not the viewport) but overflow is propagated to the viewport as described at [3.3. Overflow Viewport Propagation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-propagation). I don't think there's any official consolidated place for such info, because it would run the constant risk of becoming out-of-date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements)

Comment: Hey @zoplonix, no. My question does not pertain to default styles, but to overrides to the usual CSS rules. To my knowledge there are 3 exceptions to the normal CSS rules: backgrounds on the body also apply to the html element, overflow: visible on the html becomes overflow: auto, the background of the html element is applied to the entire canvas. My question is this: where can I find a list of all these exceptions and special rules? :)

Comment: Are you looking for CSS inheritance rules?

Comment: No, I'm looking for exceptions to the way CSS Layout Algorithms (technically "modes") usually work.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the address bar type in `about:blank`
2. Right click on the page and choose Inspect
3. Click on `<html>`
4. Look in the bottom of that window

If you made your own HTML file and changed any html attributes to specify a different version of html, it will give you different CSS in that window

Comment: This doesn't answer my question zoplonix 